# upload sql file in vm ware server using putty

Tags: mysql, linux, vmware, remote-access, putty

Hai I am trying to upload mysql database using putty i have tried few commands,

```
mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < /var/www/html/sample.sql
```

and tried

```
plink mysql -u username -p database_name < /var/www/html/sample.sql
```

but unable to upload files to linux server any suggetions

Comment: Is this dump contains only one database?

Comment: If you need to restore a database that already exists, you'll need to use mysqlimport command. The syntax for mysqlimport is as follows:

mysqlimport -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] [backupfile.sql]

Comment: its a new database, i have uploaded to linux server using ftp now have to upload it to my sql

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: yes not valid command maria db command

Comment: Do not post important information in comments, edit your question!

Comment: whats the important information right here? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Well, your question does not contain **any** information about your problem. All you wrote was that you are *"unable"*.

Comment: oh.. i will update

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax

```
mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -p --database={DB-NAME} < /var/www/html/sample.sql
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that c                                                                                       orresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql                                                                                        -u root -p --database=choice < /var/www/html/choice.sql' at line 1

Comment: I think you have created the dump using mysql command  instead of mysqldump.

Comment: so what to do can i drop the database ?

Comment: Create another dump using mysqldump and try to import that

Comment: mysqldump -u root -p choice > /var/www/html/choice.sql i tried this but asking for password after than no response going to next line on terminal

Comment: So you are not getting anything in /var/www/html/choice.sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159730/discussion-between-java-and-pattatharasu-nataraj).